# MYSQL: Sum rows with a particular value

Tags: mysql, nested, sum

I've got a table with many rows that contains different type of values.
Every row has a 2 column: `FieldName` and `FieldValue` and I need to sum all rows of *counter type*

```
SELECT FieldValue as somma FROM `my_values` as value WHERE value.`FieldName` ='counter'
```

I tried this query

```
select sum(value.somma) as a from (
SELECT FieldValue as somma FROM `my_values` as value WHERE value.`FieldName` ='counter'
)
```

But I have the following error:

> #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: That error is caused by your subquery not having an alias. It should work if you put almost anything after the last `)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a simple sum()

```
SELECT sum(FieldValue) as somma 
FROM `my_values`
WHERE FieldName` ='counter'
```

or if you need using alias then prefix the column in proper way

```
SELECT sum(value.FieldValue) as somma 
FROM `my_values` as value WHERE value.`FieldName` ='counter'
```

Comment: The simplest things are the best

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use

```
SELECT sum(FieldValue) as somma 
FROM my_values as value
WHERE value.FieldName ='counter'
```